# Removing and creating a file in git and the file history: possible bug?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

I have a file that I removed using `git rm` after which I committed successfully.
Later on, I created a new file named after the original file and commit successfully.
But when I look at `git log file.txt` on this file, instead of seeing a single commit, I see the history of the earlier deleted file.
I was expecting the deleted file to be distinct and unrelated to the new file although both are named the same.
I tried with `--follow` and I still see the same behaviour.

Did I miss something? (Or is this a bug? I’m using version 2.25 of git on Fedora )

```
git --version
git init
touch master.txt ; git add . ; git commit -m "Master original created"
git rm master.txt ; git commit -m "Master original Removed"

echo junk >dummy ; git add . ; git commit -m "Dummy Commit"

echo "only line in Master" >master.txt ; git add . ; git commit -m "Master New Created"

git log --oneline --no-rename master.txt
git log --oneline -M100% --no-rename master.txt
```

========================================

```
it version 2.25.1
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/sony/gitwork/tt/.git/
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
rm 'master.txt'
[master ad596ad] Master original Removed
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
 delete mode 100644 master.txt
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
[master 02492e1] Master New Created
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 master.txt
02492e1 (HEAD -> master) Master New Created
ad596ad Master original Removed
42c32af Master New Created
1a057ca Master original Removed
beb0903 Master original created
02492e1 (HEAD -> master) Master New Created
ad596ad Master original Removed
42c32af Master New Created
1a057ca Master original Removed
beb0903 Master original created
```

Comment: Try `git log -M100% file.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug, but the result of the Git rename detection based on the *content* of the file, similar enough for Git to consider the new file to be the old one, renamed.

A [`git log --no-rename`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46807414/6309) would not display the past commits.

Buy the true solution would be to undo that commit, and:

- commit the deletion
- then, [in a separate commit, commit the new file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34471202/6309)

Comment: I tried both --no-rename and also -M100% to no avail.

Comment: @SonyAntony Why are you using the same name for `git rm` and the new file? The idea to avoid a common log is to avoid it between two different files with different names but similar content: `git rm file1`, and commit, then `git add file2` and commit.

Comment: @SonyAntony Is your worflow based on deleting, then adding again the *same* file name?

Comment: No @VonC ...As I said, I was just trying out various things in git.. This just happened to be a behavior I did not expect

Comment: @SonyAntony Git determines the "file identity" through its content: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55617347/6309 (and https://stackoverflow.com/a/36563833/6309). Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51662141/6309. More on history and similarity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51795091/6309